# How to place content in right place in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code, and when I call the function with mydomain/index.php/blog   everything works, but the content i.e "index" in this case is being displayed in the top of the page.
I want it to be displayed in the content area, that i have defined in my css. Whats the problem?

```
<?php
    class Blog extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index(){

            $this->load->view('template/header');
            echo "index";
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: See the [CodeIgniter documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) about rewriting the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to display output to the browser in CodeIgniter. Using the CI views and just echoing out the data. The `echo` command executes immediately, so that's why it is at the top of the page. The `load->view` method is executed within CI in the output library - so it's not executed exactly in order of your echo statement.

I would say to create another view for your content, then call all views like this:

```
$data = array('content_html' => 'index');
$this->load->view('template/header');
$this->load->view('template/content', $data);
$this->load->view('template/footer');
```

Your content view could just echo out the `content_html` variable:

```
// views/template/content.php
echo $content_html;
```

Alternatively, you can control the content in your controller (although, not the best of ideas):

```
$header = $this->load->view('template/header', array(), TRUE);
$footer = $this->load->view('template/footer', array(), TRUE);

echo $header;
echo "index";
echo $footer;
```

Passing `TRUE` as the third parameter to the `load->view` method returns the view as a string instead of outputting it to the browser - allowing you to control the output.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display data in your content area

```
<?php
    class Blog extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function index(){
            $data['content'] ='Your content';   
            $this->load->view('template/header');
            $this->load->view('template/content_template',$data);                
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
        }

    }
    ?>
```

And create a separate template file for content and paste this code inside your content file.

```
<?php
print $content; 
?>
```

Also refer this url
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html